# "You must wear a suit TO an interview" vs "You must wear a suit FOR an interview"

Tags: prepositions

In the sentence-

> You must wear a suit to an interview

shouldn't the **to** be replaced by **for**? Or what's the difference between these two here?

Comment: When it comes to prepositions, there is a lot of crossover in meaning or usage. Rather than just ask A or B, you should give your rationale for using them in your context. The interview could be a location (to) or an event (for), but I can't tell which meaning you intend.

Comment: The former makes me think you need to be wearing a suit to an interview while the latter makes me think you could possibly be denied an interview if you don't wear one.  "To" seems like helpful advice from someone outside of the interview while the "for" sounds like a mandate from someone involved in the interview.

Comment: @RichardTuttle "for an interview" could indeed mean something like "to receive an interview", but to vs for doesn't affect whether it's advice from outside or mandate from someone involved.

Comment: While both sentences mean basically the same thing, using 'to' has a potential implication that you can take the suit off once you arrive at the interview, whereas using 'for' implies you'll be wearing it at the interview and may remove it afterward. No one should make this misunderstanding, but it could potentially be the basis for a joke.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The difference is fairly slight. Some cases you could use either and others one or the other would only work.

To would be used for a location or an event (could imply motion)

For would be for a purpose, benefit, etc

The trick is that a location/event is often a purpose; your purpose is to go to that location/event. With verbs ("to wear to run"), the trick is that some words can be both verbs or nouns (e.g. run as a noun is an event of running). In these cases, both may be grammatical, but slightly change the meaning.

Examples:

> You must wear a suit **to** the wedding
>
> You must wear a suit **for** the wedding

Either of these works because a wedding is either the event or the purpose for wearing the suit.

> You must wear shoes **to** the bank

Bank is a location so this works.

> You must wear shoes **for** the bank

This still could make sense, but it would be somewhat less commonly used than **to** the bank.

> You must wear boots **for** safety

Purpose, so it works

> You must wear boots **to** safety

This doesn't make sense.

> You must wear a hat **to** garden

versus

> You must wear a hat **for** gardening

You cannot wear a hat "for garden"; for in this case would expect a noun, which then needs an article ("a garden" or "the garden") and would now be a location.

If you say

> You must wear a hat **to** gardening

You've changed the meaning slightly; gardening is now an "event" as opposed to an intended action (purpose).

Comment: I think you're getting at the right concept: 'to' is for locations, 'for' is for events or processes. If the thing is both, use either. But some of the specific examples aren't great. I'm going to do something at the bank, so going to the bank is a process, so I could be told that I need shoes "for the bank". This might mean that I won't be allowed in the bank without shoes.

Comment: "for the bank" does work although it seems less likely to be used in practice. I've expanded definitions and added examples when using with a verb complement. English can be rather flexible.

Comment: +1, I agree. Super flexible. Important to get that across in these answers.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "you must wear boots to safety" does have a grammatical meaning, but a dramatically different one: if you are currently in an unsafe location, and you're heading towards a safer one, you can say that you're heading "to safety". If there's jagged ground in between, you may want to wear boots to there. ;)

Comment: @neminem that meaning is possible, but it's not real likely. I'd expect to have "wear boots to get to safety" for that meaning

Comment: @eques could you please elaborate a bit more? makes sense, but i get confused again :S

Comment: @ArdisEll the basic rule is to = locations/events, for = purpose. There is some overlap or ambiguity. A location/event can be a purpose, so either one could work in many cases. Where it would be distinct would be like wearing something to <location/event> because you have to wear it for <some other purpose later>

Answer (score 6):

Because we can conceptualize **the interview** either as an event or as a proceeding, we can say either:

> Should I wear a suit **to** the interview?  (event)
>
> Should I wear a suit **for** the interview? (proceeding)

A matador might say:

> I am going to wear my best brocade  **for** the bullfight.

and a person who plans to attend the bullfight as a spectator might say:

> I am going to wear my *Viva el Toro* t-shirt **to** the bullfight.

Comment: For both of your last two examples, swapping to and for doesn't alter the meaning at all.

Comment: The matador does not wear his brocade to the bullfight.

Comment: Does the bride wear a bridal gown *to* her wedding?

Comment: Sure he can. If he's wearing the brocade for the bullfight, he can wear it to the bullfight.

Comment: Likewise for the bride. She can wear her wedding dress to her wedding or for her wedding.

Comment: The preposition **to** is used to mean "when *attending*". *What are you wearing **to** the dance?* The bride doesn't *attend* the wedding. The matador does not attend the bullfight.

Comment: Where do you get that rule? Also, if the bride doesn't attend the wedding, she isn't getting married. She isn't attending as a guest, but she is still present (hence "attending"). "I wore a tuxedo to my wedding" is entirely valid and understandable.

Comment: It's not a violation of any "rule" but a semantic thing. *I wore a tuxedo to my wedding* sounds very strange to my ear. It's not that I can't understand it, but I would say **at** there. Does the bull attend the bullfight?

Comment: The idea that "to" means "when attending" seems far-fetched. As I established in my answer, "to" is also used for a location. One doesn't attend a location. "I wore a tuxedo at my wedding" is also valid; the only real difference is that "to my wedding" can be interpreted to include the process of arriving at the event/location whereas as "at" wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

> You must wear a suit **to** an interview.

This is okay, because you will go **to** an interview. It's just like

> You must take a suitcase **to** an interview.

We would use "for" in sentences like

> You must be prepared **for** an interview.

Comment: +1. Though we could ask "Should I dress casually or formally for the interview?"

Answer (score 0):

I would regard the preposition *to* as indicating time/place, while the preposition *for* would indicate purpose.  Consider the following sentence:

"Because you will be proceeding straight from the interview to a wedding
   reception, you will need to wear your suit *to* the interview".

If people with whom you're interviewing might not particularly appreciate your suit (depending upon the circumstances, they might have preferred that you wear work clothes that could tolerate getting dusty), you wouldn't be wearing the suit *for* the interview.  Nonetheless, you would still be wearing the suit *to* the interview because you would be wearing the suit at the time/place where the interview would occur.