# Preposition dilemma: "new to me" or "new for me"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

> Very soon I realised that the task was new **to** OR  **for** me.

Which is the correct  preposition to use in this sentence:  *to* or *for* ?

Comment: See this question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/95080/you-must-wear-a-suit-to-an-interview-vs-you-must-wear-a-suit-for-an-interview/95083

Answer (score 2):

The idiom is "new to somebody", so the more natural form is "The task was new to me".

The alternative, "The task was new for me" is grammatical, but less natural.